# Why is `_isurl` an instance method rather than a static method of a numpy `DataSource`?

Tags: python, oop, numpy

The `DataSource` class in the `numpy.lib._datasource` module has a short instance method [`_isurl(self,path)`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/_datasource.py#L257) that tests if `path` is a net location. It does not use in any way the instance and its members.
It is true that (in python 3.3) it can be used without actually creating an instance with:

```
DataSource._isurl(None,path)
```

Yet, as I see it, this is a typical case for a static method (even a regular function defined outside of any the class). Are there any benefits in writing it as an instance method?

Comment: You should probably [ask the numpy developers](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/mailing-lists.html) directly. I agree that a staticmethod might make more sense in this case, but that's an undocumented method that's not really intended for end-users anyway. Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/_datasource.py#L257-L273), it would be trivial to reimplement it yourself using `urllib` if it really bothers you.

Comment: When was this module first added to `numpy`?  Maybe it goes back to a time when `@staticmethod` was not available.  Some parts of `numpy` originate in the 1990s.

Comment: @hpaulj probably [this commit from 2007](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/fdeac7465818652d5fb31e7e0e27f9debd0f54b8)

Comment: @ali_m I am not bothered but curious, perhaps there was a reason, eg a performance advantage. Reimplementation means duplication in this context. I intend to submit a new feature proposal to add cache control in genfromtxt family of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty confident that it was not done for performance reasons:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
else:
    from urlparse import urlparse

class DataSource(object):

    def _isurl(self, path):
        scheme, netloc, upath, uparams, uquery, ufrag = urlparse(path)
        return bool(scheme and netloc)

    @staticmethod
    def _isurl_staticmeth(path):
        scheme, netloc, upath, uparams, uquery, ufrag = urlparse(path)
        return bool(scheme and netloc)
```

Timings:

```
In [1]: ds = DataSource()

In [2]: %timeit ds._isurl_staticmeth('http://www.google.com')
The slowest run took 14.76 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.25 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit ds._isurl('http://www.google.com')
The slowest run took 12.99 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.31 µs per loop
```

In fact, both methods produce almost identical bytecode:

```
In [4]: import dis

In [5]: dis.dis(ds._isurl)
  9           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (urlparse)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (path)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          6
             12 STORE_FAST               2 (scheme)
             15 STORE_FAST               3 (netloc)
             18 STORE_FAST               4 (upath)
             21 STORE_FAST               5 (uparams)
             24 STORE_FAST               6 (uquery)
             27 STORE_FAST               7 (ufrag)

 10          30 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (bool)
             33 LOAD_FAST                2 (scheme)
             36 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    42
             39 LOAD_FAST                3 (netloc)
        >>   42 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             45 RETURN_VALUE        

In [6]: dis.dis(ds._isurl_staticmeth)
 14           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (urlparse)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (path)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          6
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (scheme)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (netloc)
             18 STORE_FAST               3 (upath)
             21 STORE_FAST               4 (uparams)
             24 STORE_FAST               5 (uquery)
             27 STORE_FAST               6 (ufrag)

 15          30 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (bool)
             33 LOAD_FAST                1 (scheme)
             36 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    42
             39 LOAD_FAST                2 (netloc)
        >>   42 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             45 RETURN_VALUE
```

Either way, it seems very unlikely that `_isurl` would ever be used in a performance-critical situation.

I can't speak for the numpy developers, but I can't think of any particular reason why not to make `_isurl` a staticmethod rather than an instancemethod. If I were designing a similar class from scratch then I would probably make it either a staticmethod or just a plain old module function.

Comment: I would call the static method thus: `DataSource._isurl_staticmeth('http://www.google.com')` If the sole reason for creating the instance is to call the method then it should be icluded in _%%timeit_. The instance method is then 50% slower

Comment: There's still absolutely no performance difference between `ds._isurl_staticmeth` and `DataSource._isurl_staticmeth`. If you were going to call `ds._isurl` lots of times then of course you would want to instantiate `ds` only once rather than creating a new instance on every call (or using `DataSource._isurl(None, pth)` as in your question). This all sounds like premature optimization to me, anyway. Is `_isurl` really a performance bottleneck?